# Well-known namespace prefixes

Tags: xml, namespaces

Dr Macro [says](http://drmacros-xml-rants.blogspot.com.au/2006/02/i-was-wrong-sort-of-about-namespaces.html):

> In practice its rare that namespace prefixes clash because most
>   namespaces are well known and defined with a conventional prefix that
>   is likely to be unique among the set of namespaces likely to be
>   combined (again, the more general case of willy-nilly combination of
>   unexpected stuff just doesn't much happen).

Nevertheless, I'd like to pick a namespace prefix that isn't in common use.  I guess I could Google my intended prefix(es), but does anyone know of a list of conventional prefixes, ideally with some measure of how common/obscure they are?

Answer (score 3):

The important thing about namespaces is that the prefix is arbitrary and can be easily changed.  It isn't the prefix that is standardized, it is the namespace url, and those won't conflict because they use the domain registration system to prevent conflicts.

Comment: yes, I understand the prefix is arbitrary, but still, I'd like to avoid a collision with a prefix someone else is likely to be using in incoming XML, when I specify a preferred prefix for my namespace in a JAXB namespace prefix mapper.

Answer (score -1):

Prefixes are totally irrelevant. Prefix "collisions" do not occur when using most XML APIs to construct XML. Even if you supply a prefix to such an API, it will be treated as a "preferred" prefix, and will be ignored in the case of a collision.

Only the namespace needs to be unique.

Comment: Irrelevant in theory, but not in practice.  In practice, when you are reading XML, it is nice if the prefix stays the same from document to document.

Comment: How does it even matter? What XML API are you using where this matters at all?